# error running javadb in jre 8 / netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, javadb

I recently updated to jre8. It seem that the present security settings are really nasty. I am unable to run javadb

I get the following error

Mon Mar 31 02:04:54 IST 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Mar 31 02:04:54 IST 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")

what are the steps taken by me

- changed the permission in java.policy file to listen to 1527 (also added resolve)-but to no avail

this is what http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-known-issues-2157115.html gives out

> Bug 8030961
>
> Area: Java DB  Synopsis An additional permission may be needed to
>   bring up the Java DB network server. In particular, the startup
>   scripts in  may fail to boot the network server.
>
> While attempting to boot, the network server may fail and raise the
>   following error:
>
> access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527"
>   "listen,resolve") java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve") To fix
>   this problem, you must bring up the network server with a security
>   policy that includes the missing permission. Instead of booting the
>   network server as:
>
> java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start boot the network
>   server as follows:
>
> java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=${yourPolicyFile}
>   org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start where
>   ${yourPolicyFile} is a file containing a customized version of the
>   policy file described in the Java DB Admin Guide section titled Basic
>   Network Server security policy. You must customize that generic policy
>   file to fit your application. In addition, you must add the following
>   permission to the permissions block granted to the
>   ${derby.install.url}derbynet.jar codebase:
>
> permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:${port}", "listen";
>   where ${port} should be replaced by the port number where the network
>   server listens for incoming connection requests. By default, that is
>   port 1527.

now I exactly not sure what to do 
*do I need to do any additional stuff
*found derbynet.jar ( as an executable jar file) how do I edit, what do I edit

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is confusing: did you change your java policy settings or not? Did you try this: http://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/javadb-derbydb-access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-localhost1527-listenresolve/

Comment: @BryanPendleton,sorry for the late response, but followed the instructions cited in the article, nope did not work, still access denied...

Comment: @StevenMai,, not a duplicate because you had the change of policy to alleviate the problem in jdk 1.7 whereas here it is 1.8 and such a measure doesn't simply work!!!

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to show

1) How your start the server (cmdline)
2) The stacktrace you get
3) Content of your policy file

Alternatively you could study the comments in the [corresponding Derby Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6438)